# Pandas - groupby multiple columns and the compare averages of counts

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a 4000 record plus pandas dataframe with records for individual events by time stamp

```
Timestamp            Date        Holiday  DayOfWeek
2017-01-01 02:25:00  2017-01-01  True      Monday
2017-01-01 12:25:00  2017-01-01  True      Monday
2017-01-02 03:45:00  2017-01-02  False     Tuesday
2017-01-02 15:55:00  2017-01-02  False     Tuesday
2017-02-03 01:01:00  2017-02-03  False     Thursday
2017-02-03 4:25:00   2017-02-03  False     Thursday
2017-04-03 4:25:00   2017-04-03  True      Monday
```

What I'm trying to do is compare the means of events per day by day of the week and if it was on a holiday.
So for each day of the week, compare the the average number of events per day for when that day was a holiday vs when that day was NOT a holiday.

```
events.groupby(['DayOfWeek', 'Holiday']).count()
```

Will get me the number of events for each day of the week by holiday

```
DayOfWeek Holiday  Count
Monday    True     50
          False    34
Tuesday   True     32
          False    23
...
```

But I can't figure out how to combine this with the number of events per individual date

```
events.groupby('Date').count()
Date        Count
01-01-2017  2
01-02-2017  2
01-03-2017  4
....
```

I want a data frame more like

```
DayOfWeek Holiday  Mean
Monday    True     4.5
          False    3.23
Tuesday   True     2.1
          False    3.2
...
```

And then ideally make a bar chart from it.

But can't figure out how to combine the operations to create what I want first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for should be

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'DayOfWeek', 'Holiday']).count().reset_index().groupby(['DayOfWeek', 'Holiday']).mean()['Timestamp']
```

First we group by `date` (and `DayOfWeek` and `Holiday` to preserve the columns - they will always be the same for any single date), count the records per date, reset the index, group by `DayOfWeek` and `Holiday` and calculate the mean.

For the sample data you provided this results in

```
DayOfWeek  Holiday
Monday     True       1.5
Thursday   False      2.0
Tuesday    False      2.0
```